# What are the things that i have to Do and Don't when an application to be Globalized and Localized?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

**What are the areas we needed to change in the code when an application to be Globalized and Localized?**

For example

**Do**

```
string datenew = Convert.ToDateTime("10/31/2012", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        .ToString();
```

**Don't**

```
string datenew = Convert.ToDateTime("10/31/2012").ToString();
```

Comment: i got more information from this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688110

Answer (score 2):

Check this link, it will give you basic understanding: **[Internationalization tips for developers – I18N checklist](http://www.emreakkas.com/internationalization/10-internationalization-tips-for-developers-i18n-checklist)**

1. Externalize all translatable content – Take the text out of the code and place in resource files
2. Allow input of international data and foreign scripts
3. Do all string handling with Unicode
4. Use system functions for date/time and numeric formatting
5. Use system functions for sorting and string comparison

Also, check this - **[SDLC Checklist for Globalized ASP.NET Web Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14323/SDLC-Checklist-for-Globalized-ASP-NET-Web-Applicat)**